# Is there legitimate scientific debate about evolution?

Tags: evolution

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Demonstrable and repeatable examples of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution)
>   [Does "The Fossil Record" evidence sufficiently support evolution?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/101/does-the-fossil-record-evidence-sufficiently-support-evolution)
>   [Have we observed evolution through natural selection in areas of high child/youth mortality?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/have-we-observed-evolution-through-natural-selection-in-areas-of-high-child-yout) 
>   [Does DNA add credibility to the theory of evolution?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/does-dna-add-credibility-to-the-theory-of-evolution) 
>   [Are evolutionary explanations "Just so stories"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/are-evolutionary-explanations-just-so-stories)

Some creationists argue that there is legitimate scientific debate about evolution and that students should be taught the controversies and debates.  For example, in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFjoEgYOgRo), a creationist argues that evolution is not universally accepted and there are many flaws in the theory.  She argues that the controversy over evolution is being ignored by the mainstream.

Is it true that there is a great deal of scientific controversy over evolution, or is it almost universally accepted in the scientific community?

Comment: Other possible dupes: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/101/does-the-fossil-record-evidence-sufficiently-support-evolution http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/have-we-observed-evolution-through-natural-selection-in-areas-of-high-child-yout http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/does-dna-add-credibility-to-the-theory-of-evolution http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/are-evolutionary-explanations-just-so-stories

Comment: There is the [Scientific Dissent From Darwinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Scientific_Dissent_From_Darwinism) ([website](http://www.dissentfromdarwin.org/)), so there seem at least some scientist which dissent from the theory of evolution.

Comment: I disagree mine is an exact duplicate.  Which article referenced handles the claim that there is a major debate about evolution?  Just looked through all the "duplicates" and haven't found the answer to my question.

Comment: Casey, in answer to your question:  No.  There is no _legitimate_ controversy as religious organizations such as the Discovery Institute would imply.

Comment: @MartinScharrer taking the definition of "scientist" very loosely.  ;)  Most of the wiki article is about the dishonesty and unqualified respondents.  Again, nothing _legitimate_ about any "controversy".  But then, we are always discovering new things and understanding the theory better.  :)

Comment: Quite frankly, even if there *is* a legitimate scientific debate -- scientific theories are pretty much always undergoing revision and scrutiny as new discoveries are integrated into the pool of knowledge, after all -- the 'arguments' that creationists keep trying to put forward in the mistaken belief that they understand what they're talking about have no part in it.

Comment: I wish this was reopened. I think it is distinctive from the answers marked as duplicates. I also have an answer - Google for "Project Steve".

Comment: @vidstige I like how they are gender neutral by allowing signatures from "Stephanie" as well.