# Did every signer of the Declaration of independence (US) said they believed that men and women were created?

Tags: evolution, geology, earth

According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikax0Y0NJsY&feature=youtu.be) video, Mike Pence said:

> every signer of the Declaration of independence believed that men and women were created and were endowed by that same creator.

Did they express such belief?

Comment: This would fit better on [biology.se] except that I'm sure that (1) it would be a duplicate, and (2) it would be downvoted into oblivion, as there are close to zero serious biologists who believe in creationism over evolution.

Comment: Also, duplicate here of http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8822/17804 et al.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin you should reference that actual person being quoted if you know.

Comment: Downvoters, I would like to know why this question is not helpful or unclear or shows no research effort. Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: I suspect you were downvoted by Americans or others familiar with the most famous line from the Declaration of Independence, which - perhaps unfairly - makes this question look either politically motivated or lacking in research.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48547/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-sakib-arifin-did-every-signer-of-the-declarat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are **created** equal, that they are endowed by their **Creator** with certain unalienable Rights

[The Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration)

Comment: Read literally, this only resolves half of Pence's claim: it doesn't express a belief that **women** were created.

Comment: @NateEldredge: according to LDOCE: "man --- 3 person [countable] a person, either male or female – used especially in formal situations or in the past"

Comment: Given that this document came well before any good competing theories were available, I'd say that it was the only way they had to express their intent that human rights should trump kings and queens.